# Can I 'poison' a value in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'd like to be able to poison a signal in VHDL so that any subsequent consumers of it get a poisoned value too so I can find unintended links. Its fine if poisoning works in simulation only.

Background: I've made a CPU in VHDL and want to pipeline it. Before I do that I want to make sure that no part of the pipeline is sampling outputs from other parts when it shouldn't. So all the parts in the pipeline create and hold their valid output for exactly one clock cycle and set the various outputs to zero at other times. And for those times where the output is zero the next stage in the pipeline shouldn't even be looking at those values. But I want to confirm it under simlation.

So I tried setting the outputs to 'U' or 'X' during the times they dont represent data and these show up in the simulator as orange or red, but if I force them to be erroneously sampled the bad values dont propagate. So it seems like neither U nor X are what I want. Without changing the consumers of these (e.g. calling `is_x(..)` in hundreds of places) is there any easy way to poison those values when running under the simulator.

If it matters, this is on a Spartan7 based Arty board with the free version of Vivado.

Comment: Have a look at aliases to external signal names and forced signal assignments. This can overwrite values of any signal in the design.

Comment: This is what assertions and property checkers are for. Try a simple `assert`, move on to OVL or PSL if it doesn't do the job. If you're set on eyeballing U/X, you should find out or ask why they're not propagating.

Comment: [link to some info on `force` and `release`](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_small/)

Comment: Some example code that shows your `'X'` not being propagated would be helpful.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like an XY problem. If you fully explain what is your final goal, instead of asking help about a partial and not working solution ("_poisoning_"), you could maybe get better and more interesting answers.

Comment: 'X' generally would be propagated, so start by finding out why this doesn't happen.